# Use of one column value with another column in cgridview Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a grid view like below.  Here i want to use the value of Correct answer to find which button to show.

For example if the Correct answer > 0 show tick button
             else show cross button

So How i will write that condition in the grid view ?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

    'id'=>'product-table',

    'dataProvider'=>Question::model()->searchCustom(1),

    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'qnid'),
        array('name'=>'question'),
        array('header'=>'Correct Answer','value' =>array($this,'getCorrectAnswer')),
        array(
                'header'=>'Acton',
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                'template'=>'{tick}| {cross}' ,
                'buttons' => array ('tick' => array('imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/correct.png'),
                                    'cross' => array('imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/correct.png'))
            ),

    ),
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable',
    'cssFile'=>false,

));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @naveengoyal i want to use the value of Correct answer to find which button to show.

For example if the Correct answer > 0 show tick button else show cross button so how i will write condition in the grid view

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 'buttons' => array ('tick' => 
  array('imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/correct.png',
        'visible'=>'Correct Answer > 0'),
 'cross' => array('imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/correct.png',
                  'visible'=>'Correct Answer <= 0'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
array('header'=>'Action','value' =>array($this,'getButton')),
```

and in controller

```
function getButton($data) {
  $correct_answer = // find it
  if($correct_answer > 0) {
    $button = '<a href="#" class="tick"></a>';
  }
  else {
    $button = '<a href="#" class="cross"></a>';
  }
  return $button;
}
```